# How Do I Do This - Python Class Mass Method Overload

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-class

I don't know exactly how to search for this question or find the answer. Or if it's possible the way I'm describing.
FWI, it's not `c/profile` I'm looking for. I know based on what I say that it may seem that's what I want, but as far as I can tell, it's not. I know I could probably inherit from them, but that's just essentially making something new anyway.

If I have a class the has some methods defined, and I wish to do testing. Is there a way I can create a wrapper/decorator or some type of logger, as to when all (or possible selected) methods run within a class, I run code to print what method is running and how long it takes (or whatever other code I want to run).

For Example

```py
@some_decorator (what Im trying to figure out)
class Adder:
    def add(self, a, b):
        return a + b

    def more_add(self, c, d):
        return self.add(self.add(c, d), self.add(c, d))
        # return (c + d) + (c + d)

Adder().add(1, 2)
Adder().more_add(4, 5)

"""
output >>
Method "add" called
 took 1 second
Method "more_add" called
    Method "add" called
        Method "add" called
         took 1 second
        Method "add" called
         took 1 second
     took 3 seconds
 took 3 seconds
"""
```

I would like to do this without individually going in and overloading/overriding/decorating each method.
I hope this makes sense.

P.S. I'm not currently worried too much about the syntax or whether exactly how I typed it, it would work. Thanks!

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html.

Comment: "I would like to do this without individually going in and overloading/overriding/decorating each method. " sure, but you can just do that programatically. So loop over the attributes of your class, select the methods you want, then decorate them.